# How do I make data in UITextView and UISlider persist once changed?

Tags: ios, swift, persistence, nscoding

I am trying to persist data in a UITextView and a UISlider so that when a user adds text or changes the slider value, this information will still appear once the user leaves the screen and then returns to it at a later time.

I have two classes that are set up to save default information by using an NSCoder.  See code below:

```
public class Category : NSObject, NSCoding {

public var topic = Topic.loadTopic


@objc
   public class Topic : NSObject, NSCoding {
    var name: String
    var usage: String? = nil
    var rating: Float? = nil

    init(name: String, usage: String? = nil, rating: Float? = nil) {
        self.usage = usage
        self.rating = rating
        self.name = name
    }

    public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(name, forKey: "name")
        if let usage = usage {
            aCoder.encode(usage, forKey: "usage")
        }

        if let rating = rating {
            aCoder.encode(rating, forKey: "rating")
        }
    }

     public required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        guard let name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as?       String
            else { return nil }

        self.init(name: name, usage: aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "usage") as? String, rating: aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "rating") as? Float)
    }


 func saveTopic() {
    let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: "topic")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "topic")
}

 static func loadTopic() -> Topic? {
    if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "topic"),
        let savedTopic = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? Topic {
        return savedTopic
    }

    else { return nil }
 }
}
```

At the top of this file I Have two notifications set up so that I can have the appropriate places notified when a change has happened and update accordingly...

```
           let infoDidChange: Notification.Name = Notification.Name(rawValue: "infoChanged")
```

I am trying to save the rating and usage properties on the Topic class whenever a button is pressed on a view controller, so that the user can go back to the previous screen and then click back to screen again and still see the rating and usage in the text view and the slider.  I have used break points and was able to confirm that when the button is pressed to save the usage and rating that it does indeed save; however, I can't seem to get it to persist because every time I go back to the screen and do a po of the topic?.usage or topic?.rating it is then blank.

Here is how I have the code set up on the screen where I want to save the info and persist it...

```
    var topic: Topic?

    @IBAction func saveInfo(_ sender: AnyObject) {



//I tried making the topic its own variable so that I could pass that through the NotificationCenter post method.

        let topic = Topic(name: (self.topic?.name)!, usage: punWordUsage.text, rating: punWordRating.value)
        topic.rating = punWordRating.value
        topic.usage = punWordUsage.text

//I tried called the saveTopic method from my Topic class, it didn't seem to help or do anything...
        topic.saveTopic()
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: infoDidChange, object: topic)

//I also tried using the NotificationCenter.post method so that it passed in the topic.rating
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: infoDidChange, object: topic.rating)

    }
```

In the same file I also tried using the NotificationCenter.addObserver method whenever the view loads and then calling a method called updateViewWithNewInfo method, but this doesn't help with persisting the data either.

```
    func updateViewWithNewInfo(notification: Notification) {
        self.loadView()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(updateViewWithNewInfo(notification:)), name: infoDidChange, object: nil)

    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!  I managed to do this successfully with a tableViewController, so I have been basing my choices on how I did that, but so far no luck.

Not sure if showing the code that I used for the TVC info helps or not, but I hope it gives an idea of how I was trying to do the same thing with the UIViewController that I'm currently struggling with.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!!

Comment: That's a lot of information. However, in your `saveTopic` method you are not synchronising the `UserDefaults` and that seems to be the reason for your data not being persisted.

Comment: I am neither able nor willing to debug your whole code. You should try to present only relevant information.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner this isn't my entire code, and I was presenting what I thought might be relevant and also showing what I had done for another part of the code that did work that I was trying to recreate.  I'll see what I can trim off.

Comment: @Adeel Okay, that makes sense... I'll experiment with that.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Sure @KateOwens give it a try and if it works for you I'll post it as an answer. Thanks

Comment: @Adeel I am trying to test it, but now I'm getting an infuriating build error "command failed due to signal 11"...I looked in the info for this failure and it's going back to the saveTopic method that I Just changed...if I revert the change I just made it builds just fine, but otherwise it just fails.  Have you ever come across this?  I'm dying to test the fix suggestion that you shared with me!

Comment: Please update the code with the changes that you have made.

Comment: @Adeel will do.  Still working on getting a fix to work....

Comment: that must be painful I guess :(